# Alternative to "Patient Discharge"

Tags: word-choice, medical

I visited someone in the hospital today and was struck by some unpleasant associations from seeing "Patient Discharge" on a sign. Surely there is a better word for this...what do they call it in UK countries?

Comment: That's what we call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

> Patient Release

would be better?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely better.

Comment: Patient Release sounds *much* more enjoyable... a real happy ending to a hospital stay ;)

Comment: In the sense that "If you're patient enough,you will soon be released"? :P